# Neovim source code: what is if_true in options.lua?

Tags: neovim, lua

The defaults that Neovim has are specified in [`src/nvim/options.lua`](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/master/src/nvim/options.lua). I'm trying to understand this source,

Let's take for example, something like `backup`

```lua
    {
      full_name='backup', abbreviation='bk',
      short_desc=N_("keep backup file after overwriting a file"),
      type='bool', scope={'global'},
      varname='p_bk',
      defaults={if_true=false}
    },
```

If I look at the `defaults` line, I can see basically ignore `if_true=` and always reason about the default,

```
defaults={if_true=false}
```

I can verify with `nvim -u NONE -i NONE --clean` that these are

```
defaults={false}
```

Why does `if_true=` exist, what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

This is a minor implementation detail which is only of some interest to those who contribute to Neovim.

For some obscure reason, in Neovim the C source code for options structure is auto-generated by Lua script.

As some values may depend on C preprocessor evaluation the generator script may output such directives and initialization assignments with different values. Hence, the (optional) fields `condition`, `if_true` and `if_false`.